# Run shell scripts with -x for debugging system v boot

Tags: shell, busybox

I need to debug the userspace part of the boot process and would like to run all the scripts with `sh -x` by default so I can observe what’s happening during boot.

It's an embedded system that's using busybox to provide `sh`.  `/bin/sh` is a link to `buysbox`.

Is it possible to do a system wise change of the interpreter from, `sh` to `sh -x`?

Answer (score 1):

On my system `/bin/sh` is a link to dash, so I can just replace the link with a program that executes `/bin/dash -x` and passes on the commandline parameters.

If your `/bin/sh` is a binary. Then copy it to `/bin/sh.org` and do the same as above, but executing `/bin/sh.org -x` instead of `dash`.

You'll have to make those changes as the root user.

If `/bin/sh` is a link to `busybox` you still can do the above: move `busybox` to `busybox.org` and make a binary `busybox` that checks if it gets invoked as `sh` (which is essentially what the original busybox does to take its various identities). If so insert `-x` before the rest of the commandline parameters and call `busybox`, if not (i.e. not called as `sh`) just call busybox with the commandline parameters as you go them.

However it might be easier at that point to download the sourcecode for busybox, change the source to always assume `-x` for `sh` invocation, compile it and install (make a backup of the original busybox binary anyway).

Comment: @KM. I don't think so, but I have no RedHat system to try this on (I don't even have a `/etc/grub.conf`) Why do you think that would pass on `-x` to `/bin/sh` when it gets invoked, I would assume that only affects grub (or the kernel if  `quiet` is an argument to its specification)

Comment: Updated the question. Seems like busybox implementation depends on the shortcut name. If its not `sh` busybox doesn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: @Alan updated my answer

Comment: And probably `exec /bin/sh.org -x` so that the wrapper script replaces itself with the new process and does not clutter up the process listing and memory.